# Activity not starting from Status Bar Notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I've found a lot of Stack Overflow posts about this issue but they all use the now deprecated Notification methods instead of using the Notification.Builder class.

I'm successfully creating status bar notifications, but when clicked nothing happens.  A warning in LogCat shows up:

```
Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@412d6df0
```

Here is the code I'm using to build my Notification:

```
public class LunchNotificationBuilder {

private Notification notification;
public LunchNotificationBuilder(Lunch lunch, Context context) {
    Builder builder = new Builder(context);
    Calendar reminderTime = (Calendar)lunch.getReminderTime().clone();
    builder.setWhen(reminderTime.getTimeInMillis());
    builder.setTicker("Reminder for " + lunch.getTitle());
    builder.setContentTitle("LunchBunch Notification");
    builder.setContentText("Upcoming lunch at " + lunch.getTitle());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, InviteDetails.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));
    this.notification = builder.getNotification();
}

public Notification getNotification() {
    return this.notification;
}

}
```

The Lunch class is just a data structure I created, don't worry about that.

The Context being passed in is Application.getApplicationContext().

I'm setting the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag as suggested by the documentation, and the PendingIntent has the PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT flag.

Another note: The activity I'm trying to launch (InviteDetails) works just fine when I explicitly call startActivity elsewhere in the code.  Something about this PendingIntent business isn't working.

Comment: Try to pass different requestCode in getActivity. [This works in A2.3 emulator](http://pastebin.com/Qa983XfB) but might be not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I don't know how to use Android. I was clicking the status bar at the top, not dragging down to see the full notification before clicking. my code was working. doh!